# Optimize mysql query with UNION

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement of getting next date and previous date

the table structure is as follows

```
| auto_id | id | next_date  | next_activity |
|    1    |  1 | 22-12-2012 |     -         |
|    2    |  1 | 25-12-2012 |     -         |
|    3    |  1 | 26-12-2012 |     -         |
|    4    |  1 | 28-12-2012 |     -         |
```

so i need next_day and previous_day
next_day = next_date after current day
previous_day = next_date before current_date

```
(SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE id = 1 and next_date > CURDATE() order by next_date asc limit 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE id = 1 and next_date = CURDATE() )
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE id = 1 and next_date < CURDATE() order by next_date desc limit 1)
ORDER BY next_date desc limit 2
```

Other way to do it self join the table...

Is there a way to optimize the table

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
SELECT next_date, date_diff
 FROM (SELECT *,
               @dateDiff := datediff(next_date, curdate()) AS date_diff,
               @pDateDiff :=
                  IF((@dateDiff < 0 AND @dateDiff > @pDateDiff),
                     @dateDiff,
                     @pDateDiff)
                  AS pDateDiff,
               @nDateDiff :=
                  IF((@dateDiff > 0 AND @dateDiff < @nDateDiff),
                     @dateDiff,
                     @nDateDiff)
                  AS nDateDiff
          FROM activity, (SELECT @pDateDiff := -9999, @nDateDiff := 9999) tmp
          WHERE id = 1) aView
 WHERE date_diff IN (@pDateDiff, 0, @nDateDiff)
ORDER BY next_date;
```

`date_diff` value gives perspective of prev and next dates.

- pick all dates where `id = 1`
- find the date difference between `next_date` and `curdate()` & store in an user defined variable `@dateDiff`.
- @pDateDiff is another variable which tracks maximum among negative `@dateDiff` values (our previous date)
- @nDateDiff is yet another variable which tracks minimum among positive `@dateDiff` values (our next date)
- in the end, select only those dates which are in `(-ve max, 0, +ve min)`.

PS: if you've  duplicate date entries then query may return all of them.

Comment: the problem would come when the difference is not 1 always...
so if the previous date was 9 days ago and next dates are 1,2 days respectively, we do not get the boundaries right.

Comment: @Masade Ok, check the updated query using Explain against union of three separate queries.

Comment: can you please help me understand the query.